# Recommendations on proper refactoring in a When statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, switch-statement, delayed-job

I'm trying to call two lengthy commands in a when statement, but for some reason, because of its syntax, it performs two of the commands **twice** when it is called :

```
  @email = Email.find(params[:id])
  delivery = case @email.mail_type
    # when "magic_email" these two delayed_jobs perform 2x instead of 1x. Why is that?
    when "magic_email"      then Delayed::Job.enqueue MagicEmail.new(@email.subject, @email.body)
                                 Delayed::Job.enqueue ReferredEmail.new(@email.subject, @email.body)
    when "org_magic_email"  then Delayed::Job.enqueue OrgMagicEmail.new(@email.subject, @email.body)
    when "all_orgs"         then Delayed::Job.enqueue OrgBlast.new(@email.subject, @email.body)
    when "all_card_holders" then Delayed::Job.enqueue MassEmail.new(@email.subject, @email.body)
  end
  return delivery
```

How can I make it so that when I hit `when "magic_email"`, it only renders both those delayed jobs **once** ?

Comment: I didn't know there is a `then`. May I ask what you are doing with `delivery`? Does it have a value after the case statement is finished?

Comment: I forgot to add the return at the end. In that way when this method is executed, it just peforms whichever delayed::job it lands on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this with following example:

```
  q = []
   a = case 1
   when 1 then  q.push 'ashish'
                q.push 'kumar'
   when 2 then  q.push 'test'
   when 4 then  q.push 'another test'
   end
   puts a.inspect #######["ashish", "kumar"]
```

This is working fine. It means your case-when syntax is ok. It might be you have aome other problem.

Comment: Thanks I ended up just putting both the functions together in a single delayed_job.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `return delivery` and delivery varible may be having the value to call the delayed job again. It depends on what the `then` statement returns, so try not to return anything if possible. I believe you want to do the delayed job and not return anything by using the function.

Perhaps you should just have the `case` and dont store it in any variable. I mean delivery variable has no purpose here.